# Score gets overwritten in next level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Player starts and collects fuel cans, the fuel is deposited in a larger tank and next map loads.  collected fuel sets to 0.  In second map, fuel is collected but when you deposit it, the score will be overwritten, not added to.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScoreManager instance;

    //script refs
    GasTransfer gt;
    LevelLoader levelLoader;
    //text refs
    public Text ScoreText;
    public Text StoredFuel;
    //bools ints
    public int collectedfuel = 0;
    private int score;
    public int storedFuel;
    public bool fuelDelivered;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else if (instance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);

    }
    public void Start()
    {
        gt = FindObjectOfType<GasTransfer>();
        levelLoader = FindObjectOfType<LevelLoader>();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        ScoreText.text = collectedfuel.ToString();

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F) && gt.isAtpump)
        {
            score = collectedfuel;
            storedFuel = collectedfuel;
            StoredFuel.text = score.ToString();
            fuelDelivered = true;

        }
         
        if (fuelDelivered)
        {
            gt.pressF.SetActive(false);
            levelLoader.LoadNextLevel();

        }
    }


    public void AddFuel() 
    {
        collectedfuel += 5;
    }

    public void RemoveFuel()
    {
        collectedfuel -= 5;

        if(collectedfuel < 0)
           collectedfuel = 0;
    }



    
}
```

I have looked at several videos, tutorials, unity tutorials.  That's how I got this far.  I just can't find the right combination of words to add to the existing score.

Comment: This is not solving the issue, but there is no need to add the negative condition to the `else` part, because that's precisely what `else` is for.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason your score is being overridden instead of being added to is that in your update method when pressing f and you are at the pump then, you are setting the score to whatever the collected fuel is. This means that whatever previous score existed there is replaced by the new value. You need to add a + next to your equals sign, similar to how you have it in AddFuel and RemoveFuel.

```
  score += collectedfuel;
  storedFuel += collectedfuel;
```

This will increase the values instead of giving them new ones.